Web-Scraping для сайта
Делаю Web-Scraping для сайта, нужно вывести:

'location of the property'
'the link of the announcement'
'date and time published'
'the price of the property'

Моя попытка:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://bina.az/'
response = requests.get(url)
trainings_soup =  BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

all_locations, all_links, all_date_time, all_price = [], [], [], []

for product in trainings_soup.find_all('div', class_='residences_list'):
    print(product.find('a').get('href'))
    link = 'https://bina.az/' + product.find('a').get('href')
    location = product.find('div', class_='location').text
    date_time = product.find('div', class_='city_when').text
    price = product.find_all('span', class_='price-val').text


    all_locations.append(location)
    all_links.append(link)
    all_date_time.append(date_time)
    all_price.append(price)


data_list = list(zip(all_locations,all_links, all_date_time, all_price))
column_names = ['Locations','Links', 'Date_time','Price']
bina = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns=column_names)

Вроде бы тэги поставил верно, но всякий раз выходит пустой list.
Что я делаю нерпавильно?

Попробуйте записать response.text в файл и посмотреть, что там. Возможно, там нет того, что вы пытаетесь искать.

Попробуйте имитировать браузер. Для начала хотя бы заголовки какие-то передавать с запросом. Здесь были какие-то вопросы-ответы на эту тему. fake-useragent и прочее такое.

@Crazyelf все я разобрался, там не читалось, я применил HTMLSession() и получилось. Но тут еще проблема. Там на сайте есть всякие селекторы и чтобы их все вычитать я их вроде все собрал: selectors = [
'.items-i',
'.residences-i',
'.items-i featured vipped',
'.items-i vipped'
] Но он читает всего 19 штук, хотя страница обновляется когда вниз крутишь. Что с этим делать?

Видимо страница динамическая, с подгрузкой через JavaScript. Ищите тут по слову Selenium.

@Stan если проблема решилась, вопрос можете удалить. а если у вас возникла другая проблема - опишите её в новом вопросе.

@strawdog вопрос я вижу полезным, так что скоро сам на него и отвечу
